# epson send data tools HOW to

Tags: printing, epson, posprinter

i want to send binary data (ESC/POS command) via EPSON Send Data Tools (senddat.exe)
according to there website / Manual from command prompt

If the printer is set as a USB printer class:
senddat.exe scriptfile USBPRN 
(C:\senddat.exe sample.txt ESDPRT001)

file:sample.txt
    ' Sample script of senddat
    ' Version 0.01

```
'Comment line is starting ' character
!Display line is starting ! character
.Pause line is starting . character


'Decimal data
48 49 50 51 CR LF

'Hexadecimal data
30h 31h 32h CR LF
0x33 0x34 0x35 CR LF
$36 $37 $38 CR LF

'String data 1
string1 CR LF

'String data 2
"string2" CR LF

'Special characters
"\"" CR LF
"\'" CR LF
"\\" CR LF
"\0" CR LF
```

which should be printing.

```
0123
012
345
678
String1
String2
“
‘
```

BUT it does not print any thing only creating out put in file (file name is same as PORT name in same directory) like my above command is making file c:\ESDPRT001

can any body help me in this.

Answer (score 0):

To out put the data to USB Printer Class printer, you need to set like below

```
senddat.exe sample.txt USBPRN0
```

"USBPRN0" is just example, you need to set correct # with your test PC environment

Comment: as i said i did this but it does not print any thing but making a file with name ESDPRT001

Comment: If your Epson printer are using "ESDPRT001", that is not "USB printer class" it's "USB vendor class",  so you need to set
    senddat.exe sample.txt TMUSB

Comment: how to get usb printer class?? what i am getting Devices and Printers > (Right Click printer) Printer Property > Port Tab (in port column all i see in port property "ESDPRT001:")

Comment: It need to change the printer side configuration, not PC side. Some of Epson TM printer has capability to support the "Vendor class" or "USB printer class". My understanding, TM-T88V has such of capability. Im not sure other model. You can check it with printer manual.

Comment: It's unclear where to find the USB Printer Class printer